# Is it possible to load data set without delimiter in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

Is it possible to load data set without delimiter in hive.

```
Data set:
1001KiranJava
1002AravindScala
1003JaveedOpps
1004RamC++
1005RahulHadoop
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, as long as there is a pattern to distinguish one field from another.  As an example, you can create a table in Hive using RegexSerDe

```
CREATE TABLE fixed(id int, name string)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.RegexSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES('input.regex'='(\\d+){0,4}(\.*)')
LOCATION 'file:///home/cloudera/fixed'
```

That should give you

```
+-----------+---------------+--+
| fixed.id  |  fixed.name   |
+-----------+---------------+--+
| 1001      | KiranJava     |
| 1002      | AravindScala  |
| 1003      | JaveedOpps    |
| 1004      | RamC++        |
| 1005      | RahulHadoop   |
+-----------+---------------+--+
```

The regex in the above example is not perfect but you get the idea.